# Regex expression gets 1) instead of just the number

Tags: java, regex

I want to make a pattern matching for the following:

```
FirstName LastName (ID: 1)
```

Code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([A-Za-z0-9_ ].*)(ID: (?<customerId>[0-9].*))$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(customer.getSelectedItem().toString());
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String customerId = matcher.group("customerId"); // returns 1) instead of just 1
    ...
```

The problem is that my regex expression returns `1)` instead of just `1` or any number.

Comment: Are you simply interested in the customer ID? And would the string pattern always be the same?

Comment: @JvdV, yes. The rest of the doesn't matter.

Comment: would `\\d+(?=\\))` yield valid results in your case?

Comment: @JvdV, yes but in case there are numbers in the name, it will fail.

Comment: it really shouldn't unless followed by a closing paranthesis (which your current and accepted pattern **don't** hold). Works fine for me wheather digits in names or not. Hence the positive lookahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `.*` tahtt means 0 or more any character (including the closing parenthesis):

```
Pattern.compile("^([A-Za-z0-9_( ]*)(ID: (?<customerId>[0-9]*))\\)$");
```

You can also remove the groups if you don't want to capture:

```
Pattern.compile("^[\\w ]*\\(ID: (?<customerId>[0-9]*)\\)$");
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the second more.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in the customer ID, you are overcomplicating things. As per your string pattern `FirstName LastName (ID: 1)`, and your current pattern (and that of the accepted answer) there are **no** closing paranthesis, other than after the ID of interest. Therefor a simple positive lookbehind should yield the correct result:

```
\\d+(?=\\)
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/dH037a/1). Add the end string ancor `$` if you must.